# How to find file system information in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I would like to know what the file system (FAT32, NTFS, exFAT) used by my SD card is, in chrome os.

Comment: You'll have to look up the specs (specifications) on the SD card, Make, Model sort of thing. Iv'e tried to change file systems on my SD cards, but none of the hacks or tricks or methods have every worked for me. There are commands via cmd.exe you can find, but none have them have ever worked on any of the cards that I've owned.

Answer (score 0):

Using developer mode, "shell" in crosh (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type `mount` after you have plugged in the sd-card, and look for `/dev/mmcblk1p1` (`mmcblk0` is internal emmc "disk"). Each line has "type" listed.

Tests show ChromeOS formats SD cards to FAT32 only, other partitions will show (if driver is present), but are not usable by ChromeOS User (but are usable from "crosh> shell" in developer mode)

If you meant the internal emmc, `/ (/dev/dm-0)` is read only ext2 and `/usr/local` (`/dev/mmcblk0p1`) is ext4.